# How to show hidden div, from inside iframe, after it has also hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#openframe').click(function() { 
            $('#holder').fadeOut(500); 
            $('#framer').fadeIn(500);
        });
    });
</script>

<!-- And the div and the iframe -->
<div id="holder">
    <div id="openframe"><img src="somewhere/img.jpg" /></div>
</div>

<iframe id="framer" scr="somedirectory/index.php"></iframe>
```

And inside that iFrame I've got this page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function autoResizeback(){
        $(parent.document.getElementById(window.name)).toggle(false);
    }
    $(parent.document.getElementById(window.name)).toggle(true);
</script>

<div onclick="autoResizeback()" style="cursor: pointer;" id="BACK">
    <img src="somewhere/img2.jpg" />
</div>
```

And I need that when the `#BACK` div is clicked, not only will it hide the iFrame that it is in, it will also 'show' or 'fadeIn' the div that was hidden, `#holder`.

Could I do that in the `autoResizeback()` function? or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$('#holder', parent.window.document).fadeIn(500);
```

to access the element from the iframe.